# How to add lines and text to boxplot?

Tags: r, boxplot

I am trying to add lines at the 85% and 95% percentiles on a boxplot and the records at that percentile.
Here is my code:

```
boxplot(x[x>0], log = "y") +
  abline(h = quantile(x,0.85), col = 'red') +
  text(y = quantile(x,0.95), labels = quantile(x,0.95), col = 'red')
```

It shows me the error message:

```
Error in boxplot(x[x > 0], log = "y") + abline(h = quantile(x, 0.85),  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

However, it is working, but without the text! I would be grateful if you could help me with this

p.s the x is a vector of transactions data (highly skewed), hence why I am using the log on y.

Many thanks

Comment: You cannot add to the graphs with + in base R. Just use three separate statements. `boxplot(x[x>0], log = "y"); 
  abline(h = quantile(x,0.85), col = 'red');
  text(y = quantile(x,0.95), labels = quantile(x,0.95), col = 'red')`

Comment: @G5W thank you! Is there away to show the value in text in a better way ?

Comment: Since I do not have your data,  i cannot recreate your graph to propose improvements.

Comment: It’s simply a vector of Typical income data (right skewed with small number of very large values)

Comment: So aren't they all positive? why do you need `x[x > 0]`  ?

Comment: There are so zeros

Answer (score 0):

I think that you wanted lines for both 85% and 95%.  This makes both lines and labels them using some bogus data. I also added `options(scipen=5)` to avoid scientific notation on the y axis.

```
## Bogus data
set.seed(1234)
x = pmax(rnorm(400, 225, 70), 0)^2

options(scipen=5)
boxplot(x[x>0], log = "y")
abline(h = quantile(x,c(0.85, 0.95)), col = 'red') 
text(x=0.6, y = quantile(x,c(0.85, 0.95)), pos=c(1,3), cex=0.8,
    labels = round(quantile(x,c(0.85, 0.95))), col = 'red')
```

[image: Boxplot]

### Updated:

If you make the line go through the text, it is difficult to read. Since you want "alignment", maybe you would rather just have a line segment instead of a full line. That way the text can be at the same level as the line. Changing the colors is as easy as providing a list of the desired colors.

```
options(scipen=5)
boxplot(x[x>0], log = "y")
segments(c(0.8,0.8), quantile(x,c(0.85, 0.95)),
    c(1.2,1.2), quantile(x,c(0.85, 0.95)), col=c('red', 'seagreen'))
text(x=0.64, y=quantile(x,c(0.85, 0.95)), cex=0.8, col=c('red', 'seagreen'),
    labels = paste(c("85th percentile = ", "95th percentile = "),
    round(quantile(x,c(0.85, 0.95)))))
```

[image: Boxplot 2]

Comment: Many thanks for this, but I am adding a couple more lines, and the number in the text is not really aligned with the line. Is there a way to make it more aligned, or alternatively, to color the lines differently and add legends ? Many thanks